# why "Cannot read property 'call' of null" appear when I try to display my component list stocked in local storage?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to store a list of components in local storage and display it.

The problem is:

I can store my components in the local storage and display it, but, if I reload, all components added after the reload will throw this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in beforeCreate hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of null"
```

here is my store:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import VuexPersistence from 'vuex-persist';
import widgets from "./store/widgets";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const vuexLocal = new VuexPersistence({
    storage: window.localStorage,
    modules: ['widgets']
});

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        widgets,
    },
    plugins: [vuexLocal.plugin]
})
```

I'm using VuexPersistence to access local storage.

Here is my widgets store:

```
export default {
    state: {
        data: [],
     },
     getters: {
         getWidgets: state => state.data,
     },
     mutations: {
         setWidget(state, {widget, props}) {
             state.data.push({
                 widget: widget,
                 props: props,
             });
         },
    },
    actions: {
         async addWidget({commit}, {widget, props}) {
             commit('setWidget', {widget, props});
         },
    }
};
```

This is where is save my components list in local storage.

Here is where I add and display my components:

```
<template>
    <div class="body">
        <div>
            <b-card-group columns>
                <b-col v-for="widget in widgets" :key="widget.id">
                    <component :is="widget.widget" :key="widget.widget.name" v-bind="widget.props"></component>
                </b-col>
            </b-card-group>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    import cardDailyWeather from "./widgets/cardDailyWeather";

    export default {
        name: 'dashboard',
        data: function () {
            return {
                widgets: [],
            }
        },
        mounted() {

            this.$store.dispatch("addWidget", {
                widget: cardDailyWeather,
                props: { city: 'Lille' },
            });

            this.widgets = this.$store.getters.getWidgets;

            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log(this.widgets);
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    .body {
        margin: 2%;
    }
</style>
```

In the mounted() method I add a components to the local storage, get the components list from local storage and print it content.

When I run the app for the first time It display well the first component added, but, if I reload to add a new component the second component isn't displayed and throw the error. BUT, the component have been added to the local storage.

When I run first the app the console print:

```
[{…}, __ob__: Observer]
```

When I reload this app the console print:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]0: {__ob__: Observer}1: {__ob__: Observer}length: 2__ob__: Observer {value: Array(2), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}__proto__: Array

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in beforeCreate hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of null"

found in

---> <Dashboard> at src/components/widgets/cardDailyWeather.vue
       <Dashboard> at src/components/dashboard.vue
         <App> at src/components/MainPage.vue
            <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Dashboard> at src/components/widgets/cardDailyWeather.vue
       <Dashboard> at src/components/dashboard.vue
         <App> at src/components/MainPage.vue
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>
```

Comment: From what it looks like, it has a problem with instantiating  the cardDailyWeather.vue component or even higher up. Do you use the beforeCreate hook somewhere in usage?

Comment: Some component might expect data that is no there yet or is only there on first initialization  ...

Comment: @mahatmanich no I don't use the beforeCreated hook

Comment: In your mounted() method you transfer an object, in your action you just need to accept a payload object, also in your mutation you only need to accept an obj e.g. payload, and then in the mutation itself call widget: payload.widget and props: payload.props

Comment: addWidget action/mutation only receives one object but you try to access actual object key values there and therefore the action and the mutation do not receive the correct data.

Comment: I could be wrong though and you are doing it differently ... , OR could it be that state.data is empty when you reload, since I don't see anywhere where you give it the stored widgets in local storage